# Como solucionar "el proceso no puede tener acceso al archivo porque se esta utilizando en otro proceso"

Tags: c#, hilos, depuración, visual

veran, lo que pasa es que una aplicacion externa sobreescribe un bloc de notas cada cierto tiempo, yo lo que quiero hacer es que cada que cambie el archivo, lea lo que contiene el archivo, tomar el dato, guardarlo en un string, pero me sale una excepcion que dice que no se puede tener acceso al archivo debido a que esta siendo utilizado por otro servicio, agregando un while y poniendo un Thread.Sleep(); hace que funcione perfectamente, el problema es que tambien quiero sumar los valores del bloc de notas y es ahi donde el while se vuelve un problema debido a que sigue sumando el valor aunque no cambie haciendo que no obtenga la suma deseada.

```
 private  void FileSystemWatcher_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            
            
            TextBox.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
           // while (true)
           // {
                try
                {
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\Users\2921095\Desktop\Text\Supersaco.txt");
                    Nido1 = sr.ReadLine();

                    if (Nido1 != null)
                    {

                        lblGramosUsados.Text = Nido1;
                        Double.TryParse(Nido1, out PesoSuperSaco);

                    }

                    sr.Close();
                
            }
                catch (Exception a)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Exception: " + a.Message);
                }
                if (PesoSuperSaco >= 10
                )
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("terminado");
                }
            Thread.Sleep(50);
            //Thread.Sleep(50);
            //  }

            //  Double.TryParse(Nido1, out PesoSuperSaco);
            //  SumaDePeso = SumaDePeso + PesoSuperSaco;
            //MessageBox.Show(SumaDePeso.ToString());


        }
```

Comment: Y si copias el archivo y lees la copia? File.Copy(@"C:\Users\2921095\Desktop\Text\Supersaco.txt",@"C:\Users\2921095\Desktop\Text\Supersaco_copia.txt",true).

Comment: Puede que el otro programa externo no este cerrando el reader o writer que usa por eso enera ese problema, lo que podrias hacer es que cuando cambie adentro de este evento le sumes la informacion, seria unicamente cuando cambie no cada que termine el while

Comment: Intentare eso de copiar y leer la copia, lo otro que comentan de solo sumar cuando se aplique el evento el problema es que solo lo suma una vez,

Answer (score 0):

No he entendido lo del while, pero puedes utilizar una función para esperar a que el fichero ya no esté bloqueado para poder leerlo. En vez de utilizar el Thread.Sleep.

Hay varias por ahí, la que uso yo es la siguiente (no encuentro de donde la saqué, si alguien lo sabe que lo comente para poder añadir el origen y darle crédito al autor original):

```
public static void WaitReady(string fileName, int max = 50)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i < max)
            {
                i++;
                try
                {
                    using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                    {
                        if (stream != null)
                        {
                            System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Output file {0} ready.", fileName));
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Output file {0} not yet ready ({1})", fileName, ex.Message));
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Output file {0} not yet ready ({1})", fileName, ex.Message));
                }
                catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Output file {0} not yet ready ({1})", fileName, ex.Message));
                }
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
```